# Position of Hide Sidebar buton in SwiftUI

Tags: macos, swiftui, toolbar

I was looking at the Apple Design Resources and saw a toolbar that looked like this:
[image]

where the hide sidebar button is inside the sidebar. However, using SwiftUI, I cannot find how to place it here at all times instead of next to the traffic light buttons. I can add an additional sidebar button before the title but I cannot remove the initial one by the traffic light buttons.

Is there any way to alter the position of this button?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the standard sidebar button of `NavigationSplitView`with `.toolbar(removing: .sidebarToggle)` and then add your own custom one.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            Text("Main Content")
                .toolbar(removing: .sidebarToggle)
        } detail: {
            Text("Sidebar")
        }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigation) {
                SidebarButton()
            }
        }
    }
}


struct SidebarButton: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: toggleSidebar, label: {
            Image(systemName: "sidebar.leading")
        })
    }
    
    private func toggleSidebar() {
#if os(macOS)
        NSApp.keyWindow?.firstResponder?.tryToPerform(#selector(NSSplitViewController.toggleSidebar(_:)), with: nil)
#endif
    }
}
```